# Using AND OR within a IF statement of a two dimensional array in order sum the value of a row

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to sum the value of the first row of a 4x5 two dimensional array and put into the int variable `rowTotal1`.  Each object within the array has both a value and a name. If the sum of values exceeds 21 for the row AND if any of the cells within the row have any of these four names ("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD"), I'd like like to subtract 10 from the total row sum.  Below is what I have so far but it is not able to subtract 10 under the right circumstances

```
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        rowTotal1 += square[0][i].value;
            if(rowTotal1 > 22 && square[0][i].name == "AA" ||
                                 square[0][i].name == "AB" ||
                                 square[0][i].name == "AC" ||
                                 square[0][i].name == "AD") {
                rowTotal1 += square[0][i].value - 10;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Try `rowTotal1 > 21` & put brackets around your `||` conditions, eg. `(square[0][i].name == "AA" || … || square[0][i].name == "AD")`

Comment: "subtract 10 from the row" or "subtract 10 from each value of the first row"? `rowTotal1 += square[0][i].value - 10;` is adding up the values of "each value subtracting 10"

Comment: Put parentheses `()` round the OR `||` parts, because `&&` is higher in the order of operations than `||`.

Comment: @ItsPete I will try your suggestions now  Thank you!

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica I will try your suggestions now  Thank you!

Comment: @Andus I want to subtract 10 from the sum of the whole row, not the individual components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
let rowTotal1 = 0;
let hasSpecialNames = false;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  rowTotal1 += square[0][i].value;

  if (square[0][i].name == "AA" ||
                       square[0][i].name == "AB" ||
                       square[0][i].name == "AC" ||
                       square[0][i].name == "AD") {
    hasSpecialNames = true;
  }
}

if(rowTotal1 > 21 || hasSpecialNames) {
  rowTotal1 = rowTotal1 - 10;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the `if` inside the `for` because of the `i` value used?

Comment: No worries. Nice answer

Answer (score 2):

First,

> values exceeds 21

but you write

```
if(rowTotal1 > 22...
```

shouldn't it be rowTotal1 > 21?

About you question,

> rowTotal1 += square[0][i].value - 10;

What is the value for square[0][i].value?

If you want to "subtract 10 from the row",

just rowTotal1 -= 10; should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Steven, that 22 was a silly mistake. Although I believe it would be ">21" not ">=21"